# Xcode archive file create with external library

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an IOS application. I am using Facebook AsyncDisplayKit library. My project running at debug mode. But When I tried to Project Archive Then Xcode give error message. Error Message is "Lexical or Preprocessor issue". I am not using pod. I drag to my project to **AsyncDisplayKit.xcodeproj** file

**Below dessription is Facebook ASDK implementation** 
(ASDK can also be used as a regular static library: Copy the project to your codebase manually, adding AsyncDisplayKit.xcodeproj to your workspace. Add libAsyncDisplayKit.a, AssetsLibrary, and Photos to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase. Include -lc++ -ObjC in your project linker flags.)

[image]

```
My Project Direktory : /devel/workplace/app/MyApp
Library Direktory    : /devel/workplace/app/ios-libraries/AsyncDisplayKit
```

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the error message.

Comment: @MaxK added screen shot

Comment: Having the same issue. :( Will post back if I get it fixed. Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to know about solving this problem is that Archiving copies your entire project and all of the source and headers to an intermediate folder and builds it from there.  It tries to set up header paths that will work, but sometimes it doesn't understand some project setups.

You need to

1. Add a new user header path that has the right place to look
2. Because you are using <> on the import (and AsyncDisplayKit uses it internally), you need to make sure "Always Search User Paths" is set to YES

To find the right header path, the first step is to figure out where the Xcode BUILD_ROOT is.  I made a simple workspace and project to reproduce this. My xcodebuild line is

```
xcodebuild -workspace TryADK.xcworkspace -scheme TryADK -showBuildSettings|grep BUILD_ROOT
```

On my system that shows:

```
BUILD_ROOT = /Users/lou/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryADK-bsnchnrjizifmqahbifklpdekupm/Build/Products
```

Now, you need to find AsyncDisplayKit.h relative to that.  It's probably somewhere in BUILD_ROOT/.., so copy the BUILD_ROOT folder you get and type (without /Products at the end of the build root)

```
find /Users/lou/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryADK-bsnchnrjizifmqahbifklpdekupm/Build -name AsyncDisplayKit.h
```

I get a few folders.  The one that makes sense for the Archive build is:

```
/Users/lou/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryADK-bsnchnrjizifmqahbifklpdekupm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/TryADK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include/AsyncDisplayKit/AsyncDisplayKit.h
```

Under Archiving, the BUILD_ROOT is set from

```
BUILD_ROOT = /Users/lou/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryADK-bsnchnrjizifmqahbifklpdekupm/Build/Products
```

to

```
BUILD_ROOT = /Users/lou/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryADK-bsnchnrjizifmqahbifklpdekupm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/TryADK/Products
```

So, your new header path is (with my setup):

```
"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include"
```

1. Go to Xcode
2. Go to your project settings.
3. Put **User Header** in the search bar
4. Make sure **Always search user paths** is YES
5. Add a new **User Header Search Path** with the header path we figured out.

If this doesn't work, we probably didn't get everything exactly right.  The best way to debug is:

1. Build with xcodebuild -- something like:

   ```
   xcodebuild -workspace TryADK.xcworkspace -scheme TryADK build archive
   ```
2. Find your error in the output and look at the exact compiler settings that were used.  Look at all of the -I/Users/... arguments -- one of those is your user header path with BUILD_ROOT exploded to the full path.
3. Make sure it's right by comparing to the results of the find above.